# Changing colors of slices depended on text in the name

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am using Highchart in my page and I wonder if I can make pie chart more dynamic. I want to make slices, where specific text in the name appears, to be shades of green.
Some code:

```
plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
                            }
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
              colors:['#89ABD5','#3b73b9','#22436b','#08a5e1',
                ],
                series: [{
                  color:'#89ABD5',
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                  color:'#3b73b9',
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                  color:'#22436b',
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                  color:'#08a5e1',
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                },
                ]
```

I have names like: `GOOD A, GOOD B, GOOD C, etc..`, `BAD A, BAD B, BAD C, etc..` and `OTHER1, OTHER2, OTHER3, etc..`
What I am trying to achieve is when, there is a text GOOD in the name, the slices should be in shades of green, while BAD -> shades of red. Other slices should be by default.
Data is get through getJSON.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on how you are generating your series data to add to the chart. Why not put some logic in the series builder to change color based on text in string? Here is some psuedo-code:

```
//looping through your data elements that you want to be slices.
    var sliceTitle;
    var sliceColor;
    var sliceData = [];

    sliceTitle = anElement[i].name;
    sliceColor = getColorMatch(sliceTitle);
    sliceData = anElement[i].dataStuff;

    series[i].name = sliceTitle;
    series[i].color = sliceColor;
    series[i].data = sliceData;
//continue loop.
    ...
    function getColorMatch(titleText) {
        if (titleText.indexOf("GOOD") !== -1) {
            return "#somegreencolor"
        }
        if (titleText.indexOf("BAD") !== -1) {
            return "#someredcolor"
        }
        if (titleText.indexOf("OTHER") !== -1) {
            return "#someOthercolor"
        }
    }
```

Note that this assumes you do not have cases where the title contains both strings and is case sensitive.

Other cool stuff to do would be to get a palette of greens, reds, and other colors not red or green. Then when you return the color you need have it cycle through the list of available hues for that string title match. That way you wont get all the same depending on how bad/good the values are. For the "other" you can have a palette of blues/yellows. Again, picking one from the list and only repeating if you have more slices than you have colors in your list.